# Zend Framework Change parameter in route on the same spot?

Tags: zend-framework, parameters, routes

I'm not sure how to fix this, or wat is the best way to approach this. Also couldn't find enough information to get me on the right way (could be that my searching sucks..)

Anyway, this is my problem:

I defined a route in my bootstrap file:

```
 protected function _initRoutes()
    {
        $router = $this->frontController->getRouter();
        $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
        $router->addRoute(
            'delete',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/:action/:id/',
            array('controller' => ':controller',
                'action' => ':action',
                'id' => ':id',
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

This works perfectly for my update and delete actions.
Now I've added the pagination to the indexpage. The pagination expects the page parameter. Because I haven't set this in my route, it cannot pass it, so my pagination doesn't work (as in switching between results).

I understand this. But what I want is that on the index page the id parameter isn't necessary and replace this with the page parameter.

Trying another route replacing id with page didn't work.

Is there a good way to solve this in the bootstrap or is it the best way to check for the action, and depending on the action, index or update/delete, define the route. The best place would than be a plugin?

Any advice or tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working on another aspect of the application I came back to the same problem. I solved it, by specifying the routes much more.

First I deleted the `$router->removeDefaultRoutes();` rule.

And then instead of (which didn't work):

```
$router->addRoute(
            'crud',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/:action/:id', array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => ':action', 'id' => ':id'))
        );
        $router->addRoute(
            'pagination',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/:action/:page', array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => ':action', 'page' => ':page'))
        );
```

I now use this:

```
    $router->addRoute(
        'crud',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/:action/:id', array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => ':action', 'id' => ':id'))
    );
    $router->addRoute(
        'pagination',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/index/:page', array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => 'index', 'page' => ':page'))
    );
```